# Problems using an interface when creating a resource in Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a problem and I don't really know how to solve it.
I defined a column in my prism table with type Json

```
product_info Json?
```

And I made an interface for this json

```
export interface IProductInfoAction {
    price: number;
}
```

But when I try to create the resource, I get this error

```
const action: Action = await this.prisma.action.create(
            {
                data: {
                    target: data.target,
                    duration: data.duration,
                    idle_time: data.idle_time,
                    filters: data.filters,
                    type: Type[data.type],
                    score: 0,
                    sessionId: data.sessionId,
                    searched_term: data.searched_term,
                    ...(data.product_info ? {
                        product_info: data.product_info
                    } : {})
                }
            }
        );
```

```
is not assignable to type  ActionUncheckedCreateInput 
Types of property  product_info  are incompatible.
Type  IProductInfoAction | undefined  is not assignable to type
NullableJsonNullValueInput | InputJsonValue | undefined
Type  IProductInfoAction  is not assignable to type
NullableJsonNullValueInput | InputJsonValue | undefined
```

How could I still keep that interface? I need it in the code to know exactly each definition of the json objects in that column